# table header fixed on scroll down

Tags: php, html

I have a table with header on it. I need the header to be fixed when the user scrolls the table data.

my table is as follows

```
<div style="height: 300px;overflow: auto">
    <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
                <th> Nr. </th>
                <th> Name </th>
                <th> Status </th>
                <th> Date </th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
           <?php  while($record = odbc_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                       <td> <?php echo$record['Nr']; ?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo$record['Name']; ?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo$record['Status']; ?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo$record['Date']; ?></td>

          <?php }?>
          </tr>               
      </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is wrong.
this will not work. 
you have to put the table head inside  section. not .
then you can define overflow: auto and a fixed height to tbody and you will be able to scroll inside the table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ... heading
    </thead>
    <tbody style="height: 100px; display: block; overflow: auto; ">
        ... bodycols
    </tbody>
</table>
```

something like that, but pleas s dont do this.
its **very** unreliable.
please do two seperate tables, wrap them inside a div and make one div fixed height and overflow auto. two more links:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: But when i change "overflow to Auto" from table tag to <tbody> tag as u have written. It is not working in IE. It is working well in Firefox. So i have added the style to div tag and to enclose the table. please tell me which is correct. question is edited.

Comment: thats exactly what i said:  dont do this. its very unreliable. please do two seperate tables, wrap them inside a div and make one div fixed height and overflow auto.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, your code is wrong.

The *Tr* with *th*'s must be wrapped with a *thead*, the other ones by a *tbody*.

Then, you should watch the source code of [this page](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you set a fixed height on the table, if it doesn't have content or very few rows, they will expand to be very high and fill the space. I don't know if that's what you want.

This solution might work for you depending on the style of your headers. 
http://salzerdesign.com/blog/?p=191